# Is it a bug that Stack Overflow's chat domain is separate?

Tags: support, chat

I notice that Stack Overflow chat uses https://chat.stackoverflow.com as its domain, while Stack Exchange uses https://chat.stackexchange.com.

Is this a bug, or what?

Comment: Nope - there's three chat systems, chat.SO, chat.MSE and chat.SE (for everything except the previous two...)

Comment: @JonClements why would they do that?

Comment: Historical reasons mostly - you'll find a bit of background and proposals to change it etc... splattered about on MSE/MSO...

Comment: @JonClements I see. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: MSE related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86099/158100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is by design. I'll copy the answer from [Animuson over on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264527/158100) here:

> That's because they are completely different servers. We have three distinct chat servers on our network:
>
> - Stack Overflow Chat (serving stackoverflow.com)
> - Meta Chat (serving meta.stackexchange.com)
> - Stack Exchange Chat (serving the rest of stackexchange.com)
>
> Each of these chat servers is completely independent of each other and do not share the same rooms. When looking at Stack Overflow Chat, you will see all the rooms on Stack Overflow's chat servers. When looking at Stack Exchange Chat with the site filtered to Stack Overflow, you see any rooms on Stack Exchange Chat which have their parent site set to Stack Overflow. None of the rooms on Stack Overflow Chat will appear on Stack Exchange Chat, and none of the rooms on Stack Exchange Chat will appear on Stack Overflow Chat.

The reasons are probably historical, but also [performance](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/) and [deployment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248148/158100). On Meta Stack Exchange users are sometimes subject to *test* some new features. Without several servers this wouldn't be possible.